# Formatting XElement values

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Is there any way I can control the formatting of this statement?

```
var element = new XElement("Element", true);
```

So that I can get this output, for example:

```
<Element>True</Element>
```

I'm looking for a pluggable formatter, not something like `true ? "True": "False"`

I have tried to go through elements afterwards, but it seems like the constructor of XElement calls `ToString()` on the value which means I have a hard time evaluating types.

Comment: I'm guessing `new XElement("Element", "True")` doesn't quite cut it in some way? Extension methods do not partake in polymorphism so its impossible to override with extension methods. Do you control the lifecycle of the XElements? IE could an extended class (ex *MyXElement*) which just overrides *ToString()* do the trick?

Comment: I was thinking about something more generic so that `DateTime` and other types could be formatted as well. I do control the creation of the XElements and I had a go at implementing a derived version of `XElement`, where a formatter could be added at any level in the hierarchy utilizing the `Parent` property etc.

Comment: After some googling i found the following [xml-writer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y8188ze) documentation. That should provide a flexible way of formatting xml, though a bit overkill in some scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally revamped answer:

Previously I recommended XmlWriter, but as it turns out that is not possible.

I'm editing this answer since `XElement` did not preserve types the way I thought, ie in

```
var x = new XElement("element", true);
x.WriteTo(new XmlTextWriter(Console.Out)); // Write stuff to console using XmlTextWriter
```

`WriteValue(Boolean)` is never called, the value is stored as `XText` in the `XElement`.

For those interested, XElement.WriteTo calls XmlWriter.WriteElement (an extension method) which in turn calls XmlWriter.WriteString.

It is possible to change the behavior of XmlWriter.WriteString but that also changes the output of

```
var x = new XElement("element", "true"); // String instead of bool
```

since the types are not stored.

My solution would be to create a factory and through it control how XElements are created. IE:

```
class XElementFactory {
      public static XElement CreateXElement(string name, object value) {
          var type = obj.GetType();
          if (typeof(boolean).Equals(type))
             // Format the XText accordig to specification, use the XText ctor for clarification and readability
             return new XElement(name, (bool) obj ? new XText("True") : XText("False")); 
          // Maybe add additional if clauses if there are just a few special cases
          return new XElement(name, obj); // Let it through
      }
}
```

The reflection seriously hurts performance, but since we are dealing with XML my guess is that performance is not that important to begin with. If needed use a builder pattern where the correct builder gets called depending on type, ie something along the lines of:

```
Builders.First(b => b.Types.Contains(objToBuild.GetType())).BuildXElement(objToBuild); // Builders could maybe be filled by MEF?
```

This answer got kinda long (but I had something do during a long conference call =P), and in essence the issue turned out not to be a formatting problem but a creation problem.

Comment: I was specifically looking for a way to format the values in `XElement` and friends so the `XmlWriter` class is not an option.

Comment: @MikaelÖstberg I totally rewrote the answer, I did some research during a lengthy meeting.